# A counterexample to Weyl theorem on complete reducibility

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

A well known result from Lie algebras' representations is the Weyl Theorem (Theorem 6.3 of Humphreys' Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory), which states the following:

> Let $\phi: \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ be a (finite dimensional) representation of a semisimple Lie algebra. Then $\phi$ is completely reducible.

In the context of the book, $\mathfrak{g}$ is a finite dimensional Lie algebra. My question is: Is there some (easy, in the sense that do not demand too much previous knowledge) example of a finite-dimensional representation of an infinite-dimensional semisimple Lie algebra that is not completely reducible?

Comment: See [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwipgbeahZj0AhVkVeUKHcAtCdMQFnoECBkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2F0905.0893&usg=AOvVaw1wJ9TyWf4RYzx9nFvN8Gwg). I suppose you still want your Lie algebra to be semisimple?

Comment: Thank you. I wanted the Lie algebra to be semisimple as well, and I've edited the question accordingly.